# Why does my code keep throwing a KeyError?

Tags: python, dictionary, shortest-path, keyerror

I can't, for the life of me, figure out why my code is throwing a KeyError.  I feel like the values should be there - I added them all in the first `for loop` and the lists I added them to aren't empty (I've checked with print statements).  So why does line 54 keep relentlessly throwing a KeyError?  I'm sure that I've just overlooked something, but after working on this all day, I'm pretty stuck.

The functions used (graph(), and shortest_path(), etc.) are [here](https://gist.github.com/mdsrosa/c71339cb23bc51e711d8).

edgeData has the following structure:

```
{string value: [list of string values that are groupings of the values in the dictionary's keys]}
```

tagUsers has the following structure:

```
{string value: [grouped lists of string values found in edgeData]}
```

Thanks in advance.

```
from collections import defaultdict, deque
import json

class Graph(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.nodes = set()
        self.edges = defaultdict(list)
        self.distances = {}

    def add_node(self, value):
        self.nodes.add(value)

    def add_edge(self, from_node, to_node, distance):
        self.edges[from_node].append(to_node)
        self.edges[to_node].append(from_node)
        self.distances[(from_node, to_node)] = distance


def dijkstra(graph, initial):
    visited = {initial: 0}
    path = {}

    nodes = set(graph.nodes)

    while nodes:
        min_node = None
        for node in nodes:
            if node in visited:
                if min_node is None:
                    min_node = node
                elif visited[node] < visited[min_node]:
                    min_node = node
        if min_node is None:
            break

        nodes.remove(min_node)
        current_weight = visited[min_node]

        for edge in graph.edges[min_node]:
            try:
                weight = current_weight + graph.distances[(min_node, edge)]
            except:
                continue
            if edge not in visited or weight < visited[edge]:
                visited[edge] = weight
                path[edge] = min_node

    return visited, path


def shortest_path(graph, origin, destination):
    visited, paths = dijkstra(graph, origin)
    full_path = deque()
    _destination = paths[destination]

    while _destination != origin:
        full_path.appendleft(_destination)
        _destination = paths[_destination]

    full_path.appendleft(origin)
    full_path.append(destination)

    return visited[destination]
if __name__ == '__main__':
    edgeData = {'a': ['c', 'd'], 'b': ['d'], 'c': ['d'], 'd': ['a', 'b']}
    tagUsers = {'hashtag1': ['a', 'c', 'd'], 'hashtag2': ['b'], 'hashtag3': ['b', 'd']}
    shortestpaths = {}

    graph = Graph()

    users = []


    # calls function, builds graph with data in edgeData
    for key, value in edgeData.items():
        users.append(key)
        graph.add_node(key)

        for each in value:
            graph.add_edge(key, each, 1)

    # determines how many users used each hashtag
    hashtags = {}
    for key, value in tagUsers.items():
        tmpTags = key
        count = len(value)
        hashtags[key] = count

    # normally determines which hashtag was used the most
    # Here, it's pre-set
    topTag = ['hashtag1']

    # calculates the shortest path from each user to another user
    # that uses the most-used hashtag
    count = 0
    if count < 1:
        for key, value in edgeData.items():
            tmpDict = {}
            for tag in topTag:
                shortest = 10000
                for k, v in tagUsers.items():
                    if k == tag:
                        for each in v:
                            flag = False
                            if key != each
                                flag = True
                                tmpShort = shortest_path(graph, key, each)
                                if tmpShort < shortest:
                                    shortest = tmpShort
                if flag:
                    tmpDict[tag] = shortest
            shortestpaths[key] = tmpDict
            count += 1
```

The goal is for the data in `shortestpaths` to contain, for each user,
the shortest distance to another user who uses the top hashtags

The function calls are referencing this code, courtesy of [mdsrosa](https://gist.github.com/mdsrosa/c71339cb23bc51e711d8) on github.

Specifically, the error gets thrown in `shortest_path()` at `_destination = paths[_destination]

Comment: where is it throwing the error?  is it on the hashtags dict?
It looks like you may have wanted this to be a `defaultdict`

Comment: At a glance, your manipulation of `tmpDict` is all wrong. You're assigning a new empty dict to `tmpDict` on every iteration of the wrong loop, and you're `clear`ing the dict immediately after you insert it into `shortestpaths`.

Comment: `for k, v in tagUsers.items(): if k == tag:` - well that completely misses the point of a dict.

Comment: @jeremyk The error gets thrown on ` tmpShort = dj.shortest_path(graph, key, each)`. Which does (I think) reference at least one  `defaultdict` that the values from my dicts should be in (graph.nodes and graph.edges).  I've also tried replacing `key` and `each` in the offending statements with plain strings that *should* (and are, I've checked) in the default dicts.  Still get the error.

Comment: that's a function call into code you haven't included above, in the module you have imported.

Comment: @jeremyk, code for the functions has been added to the end of the question.

Comment: @user2357112 good call on `tmpDict`.  Should be better, now.

Comment: is the destination in the edges data?

Comment: @JeremyK Yes, the destination is most certainly in edgeData.  I've also tried passing two nodes directly from edgeData (both of which I'm certain were added as an edge), to no avail

Comment: Can you create a [MCVE]?  The above code with a small dataset rather than loading from external json files.

Comment: `for key, value in edgeData.items()`  key, value are not appropriate variable names here, expecially as you have not provided a sample of the data in the dict.  I'm guessing this is something like `for node, edgelist in edgeData.items()`

Comment: @JeremyK, I've just replaced references to JSON files and, instead, have added sample data

Comment: Ok, *now* the code provided is runnable and, at least on my end, produces the same error I was running up against.

Comment: OK, so the first time through this fails because you are passing the Graph object (which looks ok), but your origin and destination are both the same `A`.  You need to handle this edge case

Comment: Good catch.  `shortest_path()` is no longer called if both users that would otherwise be passed to it are the same.  And.. the error persists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding some logging to `shortest_path` shows the problem:

```
def shortest_path(graph, origin, destination):
    print 'shortest_path     Origin:%s  Destination:%s' % (origin, destination)
    visited, paths = dijkstra(graph, origin)
    full_path = deque()
    print 'paths: %s' % paths
    _destination = paths[destination]
```

results in:

```
shortest_path     Origin:a  Destination:a
paths: {'c': 'a', 'b': 'd', 'd': 'a'}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e.py", line 43, in <module>
    tmpShort = dj.shortest_path(graph, key, each)
  File "E:\kiribati\dijkstra.py", line 61, in shortest_path
    _destination = paths[destination]
KeyError: 'a'
```

You need to handle the edge case where your origin and destination are the same

One option would be to add the check `if key == each` before calling `shortest_path`

```
    for k, v in tagUsers.items():
        if k == tag:
            for each in v:
                if key == each:
                    continue
                tmpShort = dj.shortest_path(graph, key, each)
                if tmpShort < shortest:
                    shortest = tmpShort
    tmpDict[tag] = shortest
```

Also change your loop variables from `k`, `v`, `key`, `value`, `each` to something that describes the actual data

Comment: you need to quote your strings:   `dj.shortest_path(graph, 'a', 'd')`

`shortest_path     Origin:a  Destination:d
paths: {'c': 'a', 'b': 'd', 'd': 'a'}
(1, ['a', 'd'])`

Comment: Yeah, I got that to work.  I'm accepting this answer, it works beautifully with the sample data provided above.  Thank you again, I appreciate your help immensely.